# jupyter nbconvert to html: datatable and qgrid not shown in html output

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, nbconvert, qgrid

Datatables and SlickGrid tables are not shown in the final **html file** after `nbconvert`'ing a previously executed `ipynb` file.

The python libraries I am using are:

- `qgrid` https://github.com/quantopian/qgrid
- `jupyter_datatables`  https://pypi.org/project/jupyter-datatables/

### What I'm attempting

I am rendering *dataframes as html tables* in my jupyter notebook.
When executing the notebook manually all works well (i.e. the tables are shown).

For instance, a cell using `qgrid` looks something like this

```
qgrid_widget = qgrid.show_grid(my_dataframe)
qgrid_widget
```

I run the notebook, tables are shown, all works well...

### Where things break...

But when I **convert the notebook to html** afterwards, running

```
jupyter nbconvert --to html my_notebook.ipynb --no-input
```

The tables are **not** shown (while all other output is). This happens with both `qgrid` and `jupyter_datatables`.
I assume that has something to do with properly loading the underlying javascript libraries.

How do I need to run nbconvert to render these tables correctly?

Thanks

Comment: I have the same problem. Please let me now if there is a solution a workaround for this.